# Framework methods returning managed references

Tags: c#, .net

.NET arrays (both single-dimensional and multi-dimensional) have methods implicitly associated with them for accessing elements of the array, namely Get, Set and Address.  Of these, the Address method returns a reference to the element type of the array.
I know that C# does not permit the specification of such methods and that it does not permit the explicit use of these implicit methods (i.e. Set, Get and Address on an array).
However, I'm curious as to whether there are other cases of methods returning references in the .NET framework.

Comment: They are not methods.  They don't belong to a class, there is no metadata that describes them and they are not part of the framework spec. The jitter has intimate knowledge of these native C++ functions and can compile a call to them directly without any pinvoke.  The functions themselves are carefully crafted to use the FCall mechanism.  Look at them in the CoreCLR source, src/vm/jithelpers.cpp source code file.

Comment: Thanks Hans, that helps me to understand more about the status of these 'methods'.  Curious thought that System.Type.GetMembers does return them them as though they were normal methods.

Comment: Sorry, meant to add in previous comment - can one assume that no real framework methods return a managed reference (like the Address pseudo-method)?